# Place attribute below product-options

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, custom-options

I'd like to hide a special attribute and show it somewhere else on the page. I found out that the attributes are handled in:
`app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml`.

Ok, there I can hide the stuff.

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
    <?php if(strtolower($this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label']))) == "MYATTRIBUTE"): ?>
        <!-- show nothing -->
    <?php else: ?>
          <tr>
              <th class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
              <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
          </tr>
    <?php endif;?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And now I have to show this attribute somewhere else on the page, just below the fieldset with the `id="product-options-wrapper"`. Could you please tell me the file where I can find the stuff?

Here's an image:

[image: Example of attribute below options]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you attach a product view screenshot where you want to put that field?

Comment: I've updated my post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go to `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml`
- around line number 248

  ```
  <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container2" as="container2">
      <action method="setDataByKey">
          <key>alias_in_layout</key>
          <value>container2</value>
      </action>
      <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry">
          <key>options_container</key>
          <key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry>
      </action>
      <action method="append">
          <block>product.info.options.wrapper</block>
      </action>
      <action method="append">
          <block>product.info.YOUR_PHTML_LINK</block>
      </action>
      <action method="append">
          <block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block>
      </action>
  </block>
  ```
- You can see, I have added an extra part:

  ```
  <action method="append"><block>product.info.YOUR_PHTML_LINK</block></action>
  ```
- Then ceate phtml file YOUR_PHTML_LINK.phtml at: `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view`